# How to find if variable call or function call?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, javascript-objects

Note: This question is based on firestore admin SDK, but it is a general JS question.

Working with JS firestore admin SDK, this puzzled me a lot. Compare these 2 examples

Request a database value

```
admin.firestore().collection('my-Col').doc('my-doc').get().then(...)
```

Get a server timestamp is

```
admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

In 1st example, it is `admin.firestore()` , in 2nd example it is `admin.firestore`

How it is possible to have a first behavior if called as function, another behavior if called as object key?

Maybe `admin.firestore()` calls a constructor... But then, how to get static value (whatever constructor called before or not) by doing `admin.firestore`?

Comment: I don't think the body of your question matches the title, so I'm not sure quite what you want to know. But a JavaScript function can also have arbitrary properties, `function something() { ... }; something.prop = "value"`.

Answer (score 1):

From @jonrsharpe:

> "A JavaScript function can also have arbitrary properties"

You gave me the tip! Built a small example to test

```js
const bill = () => ({
  friend: "boule"
});

bill.name = "bill";

const base = {
  bill: bill
};

console.log(base.bill().friend);
// -> boule
console.log(base.bill.name);
// -> bill
```

This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, functions can also have properties on their own. In javascript, you have either primitive values (boolean, numbers, strings, null and undefined) or (all the rest) objects. And functions are no exception. They are called first-class objects. A first-class object is, quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen):

> In programming language design, a first-class citizen (also type, object, entity, or value) in a given programming language is an entity which supports all the operations generally available to other entities. These operations typically include being passed as an argument, returned from a function, modified, and assigned to a variable.

When you do something like:

```
admin.firestore()
```

You are getting the value returned by `firestore`. And it happens, that this returned value has a property on it named `collection` (a function).

However, when you do:

```
admin.firestore.FieldValue
```

You are accessing the `FieldValue` property on `firestore`.

Comment: @Franck there has been heated discussion over how to address thanks in comments. So they added the controversial clap feature. You can learn more here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/17/saying-thanks-testing-a-new-reactions-feature/